# Mysql throws an error when one table name is not surrounded by single quotes

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm building a simple app which lists teams and matches. The Team and Match databases were built with the following scripts (I'm using PhpMyadmin):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Team` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `screen_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sport_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Match` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sport_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `team_one_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `team_two_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `venue` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `kick_off` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

If i do:

```
SELECT * FROM Team
```

The script runs and I get an empty result. But, incredibly, if I do

```
SELECT * FROM Match
```

I get the following error:

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Match' at line 1

Instead, I have to do:

```
SELECT * FROM `Match`
```

And it works. I have other tables in the database but this is the only behaving like this. Any ideas why?

Comment: MATCH is a Mysql keyword. If you must use it as a table name you'll have to quote it. I suggest you change it to something that won't clash.

Comment: When naming things, [keep this page bookmarked](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) as using names that are reserved keywords proves annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match` is a reserved word in SQL

Read more here:
https://drupal.org/node/141051

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make, worst part is that sometimes you will find that reserved words work for 1 type of statement but error for other types. Just check for reserved words when you get similar errors in future :)

Answer (score 2):

Match is a Function in MySQL therefore you must put the quotes around it.

Answer (score 1):

You need encapsulate it in quotes because `Match` is a *keyword*.

See [key word list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html)